# UI Application using Spring MVC for web browser, android, iphone device

Tags: android, iphone, spring, jsp, web-applications

I have web app made using spring mvc. The web app gets jsp and renders on client.
How can I convert web UI to be better viewed on an iPhone or Android device?
I mean can I use something to sow my web UI properly on android or iphone browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Dojo or jQuery.  They both have modules to support mobile devices.  Your view tier in Spring MVC would still be jsps.